# How to textwrap contents of multiple controls aligned horizontally so that it looks like a single string?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have three controls aligned horizontally, a ListPicker, a Textblock and a ListPicker.

The content would look like,

United States of America v/s United Kingdom

United States of America - content of first ListPicker (changes the value based on item selected)

v/s - Textblock content

United Kingdom - content of second ListPicker (changes the value based on item selected)

I need to textwrap this whole string "United States of America v/s United Kingdom" as if it is the content of a single control.

Is this possible? Please help.

Comment: I can't see how it is possible to do what you want. You certainly can't wrap the text as if it were on line from a single `TextBlock`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a RichTextBox with InlineUIContainers:

```
      <RichTextBox>
        <Paragraph>
          <InlineUIContainer>
            <ListBox>
              <ListBoxItem>United states of America</ListBoxItem>
              <ListBoxItem>United states of America</ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox>
          </InlineUIContainer>
          <Run Text="vs" />
          <InlineUIContainer>
            <ListBox>
              <ListBoxItem>United Kingdom</ListBoxItem>
              <ListBoxItem>United Kingdom</ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox>
          </InlineUIContainer>
        </Paragraph>
      </RichTextBox>
```

But this still won't wrap the text inside the InlineUIContainer. It will wrap only the parts relative to one another.

If you want to be able to wrap the inside text, you need to change your approach. The only solution I can think of is to use Hyperlinks:

```
      <RichTextBox>
        <Paragraph>
          <Hyperlink Click="Hyperlink1_Click">United states of America</Hyperlink>
          <Run Text=" vs " />
          <Hyperlink Click="Hyperlink2_Click">United states of America</Hyperlink>
        </Paragraph>
      </RichTextBox>
```

and to handle the Hyperlink.Click event and instead of navigating, to display a list of items to be picked and then change the text of the hyperlink to reflect the new selected item. You may also want to try to restyle the hyperlinks

Comment: Thank you! First one is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score -1):

you can use stackpanel as follow's:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <toolkit:ListPicker VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="vs" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                    <toolkit:ListPicker VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100" />
                </StackPanel>
```

**Note: "Width" depends on you.**

Comment: -1 Did you even read the question? How does your solution wrap the text contained within your `StackPanel`? I don't believe that the question author meant that they wanted to wrap the controls in another control.

Comment: @Sheridan You are right. My question is not to wrap the controls. My question is to wrap the contents (text) of the controls as if it was a single text.

Comment: So you want to wrap the content of that control on to another control(say textblock).Right? @Meee